# TypeScript compilation and debugging of optimized minified JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, google-closure-compiler

How can I set up a devenv to write in TypeScript, hit F5 to compile it straight into a performance optimized minified JS bundle, and enter debug mode, where I can step through my TS code? It sounds straight forward, but AFAIK this is still not possible.

Right now I am writing in JS with JSDoc, and use Closure compiler to minify, but would like to switch to TS. But only if the above is possible and is not difficult to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [tscc](https://github.com/theseanl/tscc), which compiles TS with closure compiler advanced mode and keeps sourcemap information. About debug mode, not sure what exactly this means, you may set it up manually with given CLI and sourcemap output

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What I'm looking for is a setup where I can write TS code in VS Code, place a breakpoint on a line, hit the F5 key and the TS gets compiled to the same minified JS that the Closure compiler produces, then launches a browser which starts executing the JS and stops at my breakpoint. Then I can step through the code like in a normal debugger. Is this possible? If you are familiar with C# Winforms development, I want the exact same experience.